# How to get Wysiwyg module to work?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am restructuring a website built with Drupal 7 so I wanted to set up TinyMCE with the Wysiwyg module.
I followed the instruction and installed the plugin in the libraries folder. In the admin interface, I can see that TinyMCE is installed and I configured it.
But I cannot get it to work. The editor doesn't load. I then switched to CKEditor. Same result: the editor does not load.

Looking in the browser JS console, I noticed that the path to get to the plugins is wrong which results in HTTP 404 errors. The problem is that the browser is trying to get the resources at wrong path ie https://mysiteurl.com/news//themes/advanced/editor_template.js instead of https://mysiteurl.com/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js

How do I fix this? Or is there something I m missing?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with SSL. Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue?